# How to embedded font inside the .pptx file

Tags: javascript, java, apache-poi, font-embedding, aspose-slides

I am creating a .pptx file using ASPOSE.Slides. I am trying to a embed font using Aspose, but it's not working because of some issues. Therefore i am searching for an alternative option to achieve the same functionality.

I want to embed my custom font in a .pptx file. Can you please provide suggestions for embedding fonts inside MS Power Point using Apache poi or other.

*Please don't give the answers for static or local system.*

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated above you can do it easily without Apache.

[Official site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

You can view/add/delete the font by accessing C:\Windows\Fonts

Answer (score 0):

@Bhagyashree,

Aspose.Slides allows you to embed the fonts inside presentation. I suggest you to please try using following sample code on your end to serve the purpose.

```
    String dataDir = Utils.getDataDir(AddEmbeddedFonts.class);
    Presentation pres=new Presentation(dataDir+"");
    IFontData[] allFonts = pres.getFontsManager().getFonts();
    IFontData[] embeddedFonts = pres.getFontsManager().getEmbeddedFonts();
    for (IFontData font : except(allFonts, embeddedFonts))
    {
        pres.getFontsManager().addEmbeddedFont(font,EmbedFontCharacters.All);
    }

    pres.save("saved.pptx",SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

Please feel free to share if there is any issue incurring on your end.
I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

With POI 4.1.0 (which will be released by approx. Feb. 2019), I've also added [font embedding](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63028) capabilities in Apache POI too. The provided methods are only the "half story", as you can't simply add .ttf/.otf files.

For the conversion of True-Type (.ttf) or Open-Type (.otf) fonts to Office-compatible [EOT/MTX](https://www.w3.org/Submission/EOT) fonts, I'm using [sfntly](https://github.com/rillig/sfntly). The snftly classes aren't provided as maven artifacts yet and I don't like to import the whole chunk into POI nor release my repackaged version of googles code under my name, therefore you need to clone and adapt my [example project](https://github.com/kiwiwings/poi-font-mbender).

For adding a MTX font stream to a slideshow (HSLF or XSLF, i.e. `SlideShow` is their common interface) you would call:

```
org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShow.addFont(InputStream fontData)
```

For font subsetting, you would need the used codepoints, which can be extracted by:

```
org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.getCodepoints(String typeface, Boolean italic, Boolean bold)
```

For getting information about a MTX font data stream, there's a new helper class:

```
org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.fonts.FontHeader
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to change it with Apache, but you can easily change it with powerpoint ...